# Prestashop attributen veranderen / change attributes

Tags: prestashop

Is het mogelijk om de attributen binnen prestashop zodanig aan te passen, zodat ik gewoon een attribuut kan aanmaken en dan vervolgens kan selecteren aan welke producten ik dat attribuut wil hangen en vervolgens ook een prijs mee kan geven, aangezien ik voor sommige producten wel 30 attributen heb wil ik dat niet steeds product voor product instellen en zo is het helaas wel standaard geregeld binnen de prestashop attributen.

Is it possible to change the way how the attributes are used right now in prestashop, because i have a large amount of attributes for several products and i don't want to fill them product for product, so i was wondering if it is possible to change it so i can make an attribute and than indicate the attribute and the price of the attributen to one or several products.

Comment: Nobody has this same problem?

Comment: Attribute Wizzard pro is the best solution for this problem.